# Reputation link in profile broken in all meta sites except Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-interface, per-site-meta

I noticed that this reputation link:

[image: broken link picture]

seems to be broken for me in all meta sites except for Meta Stack Overflow (I get "Page Not Found"). Furthermore, I noticed that the "bounties" and "reputation" tabs are missing in these sites in my profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah...we shouldn't be linking in this case, it was just an oversight in the profile.  This will be corrected in a build rolling out right now.

As Martijn said, the tabs missing are by-design, since there are no reputation changes or bounties for child metas.

Answer (score 3):

The *tabs* are missing by design; you share reputation between the main and meta sites.

But that link should then at least point back to the main site reputation tab, or be disabled altogether.

Definitely a bug that could do with fixing.